# Show title before H2 group of posts in pre_get_posts wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to display posts according to their meta_value. If I have three posts with meta_value CD , they are in order, one below the other. What I want, is to add a CD title with H2 tag prior to the first post.  I want to do the same for DVD meta_value.

```
function pregp_wpse_97354($qry) {
  if (is_category() && is_main_query() && is_user_logged_in()) {
    $qry->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'post-2' ));
    $qry->set('cat',2);
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',10);
    $meta_query = array(
          array(
            'key'     => 'sec_special',
            'value'   => array('CD','DVD',''),
            'compare' => 'IN',
    ));
    $qry->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $qry->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_97354');
```

Comment: This is called a hook, if you want to alter the presentation of your posts you should do so in your theme templates.

Comment: Yes, perfect, using the traditional theme of twentyfourteen loop. I would like to display the H2 with the CD title before the first post with the meta_value CD and H2 with the DVD title before the first posts with DVD meta_value?